# Basic URL Routing in PHP Not working using .htaccess

Tags: php, routes

I am building a basic URL Routing in Php, I read many articles about it but when I try to do the same that not happen the write way. Here is my code

.htaccess

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The index.php page

```html
<?php

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $request;
switch ($request) {
    case '/' :
        require __DIR__ . '/views/home.php';
        break;
    case '' :
        require __DIR__ . '/views/home.php';
        break;
    case '/about' :
        require __DIR__ . '/views/about.php';
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(404);
        require __DIR__ . '/views/404.php';
        break;
}
```

and the directory structure 
[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXARA.png)

Now when I try to open the /about or /contact it will redirect me to the localhost/dashboard

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: in XAMPP htdocs folder

Comment: No I am not using virtual host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one ( also helpful if you want to use images/js/css/.. later)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf)$ /$1.$2 [END,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

> Hint: You can combine the cases '/' and '

```html
<?php

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $request;
switch ($request) {
    case '/' :
    case '' : // you can combine the cases '/' and ''
        require __DIR__ . '/views/home.php';
        break;
    case '/about' :
        require __DIR__ . '/views/about.php';
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(404);
        require __DIR__ . '/views/404.php';
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the httpd-vhosts.conf file located here: `C:\XAMPP\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

Add the following line under your Directory markup:

`AllowOverride All`

Answer (score 0):

Change your .htaccess rule to

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`